# Integrate an c# executable program with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am super new to Azure tools. I am this C# program that generates an executable that takes as input a tsv file, does some processing and generates a two separate TSV files with some metrics.

The input tsv files are generated by an Azure Data Factory pipeline, which stores it on some virtual cluster. The Exe needs to consume this tsv file once it's ready, run the program and output the TSV files to the same cluster.

Basically, my overall system would look something like this:

1. ADF ---> 2. Store in VC ---> 3. Get File from VC ---> 4. Run Parse.exe ---> 5. Output to VC

I am not sure how to do 3,4 and 5?

I have the ADF pipeline and the sink which writes to the VC.

Answer (score 0):

DF has support for Azure Function and HTTP triggers atleast